# Search/return innerhtml

Tags: javascript, string, search

How can I get Java to search/return innerHTML by a custom search term?
I have tried the following but it doesnt seem to work. I just dont know the method to use here.

```
    function search(){
    var source = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput"); 
    var action = source.search.input;
    if (action > -1){
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "found!";   
    }else{
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "not found!"
    }}
```

thank you

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: innerHTML returns a string, so `source.search.input;` makes no sense

Comment: what is it that you think this is doing? -> var action -= source.search.input;

Comment: So what are you trying to do exactly? So `userInput` is a textbox? And `info` is an element on the page?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses so far. 
User input is a textbox and button and i want the user to search 
the innerhtml contained within a div.

Comment: I would like to return the string if its in the html/div or return a "not found" string. I was under the impression that .search returned a int -1 if not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string, the syntax is str.search('searchvalue') and will return the start index in the location of the string where this value is found.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Some modifications to your code should correct the issue.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <div id="info">
        Maecenas dolor nulla, eleifend nec varius eu, consequat at elit. Proin facilisis enim sit amet ligula consectetur scelerisque. Quisque hendrerit pulvinar odio non auctor. Nulla volutpat porttitor felis, non semper lectus rhoncus vitae. Donec finibus at lectus ac dapibus. Aenean mollis erat vitae neque euismod ornare. Nullam in nunc id tellus porttitor tristique. Pellentesque commodo aliquam auctor.
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search(){
        // assume source is the element that contains the text the user is searching
        var source = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;
        // input is a textbox or entry element, so we get the value as string
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value; 
        // determine the index of the user input, -1 means no match
        var action = source.search(input);
        // populate a results element on the page with the results of the search
        if (action > -1){
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "found!";   
        }else{
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "not found!"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i just got back to my desk this morning and I'm so glad you have responded. I've only taken 2 courses so far with Duke Univeristy and im already in love with the logic. Thanks a million for the knowledge!